# Inequality of a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

So I think this should be simple but I keep getting an error.  I want someone to be 'working age' if they are between 17 and 66.  I wrote the following code but I keep getting an error.  Any pointers?

```
person['child'] = person.a_age < 18
person['working_age'] =  person.a_age > 17 and person.a_age < 66
person['old'] = person.a_age > 65
person
```

Comment: *what* error do you get? - please if possible always post the relevant traceback. Also, did you try `person['working_age'] = ((person.a_age > 17) & (person.a_age < 66))`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `person['working_age'] =  (person.a_age > 17) & (person.a_age < 66)` and see if that works.

Earlier you were asking Python to convert those arrays to boolean values so you might've got this error `ValueError: The truth value of an array is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.any() or a.all().`